# Removing readonly attribute inside 3 divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

i am creating a to-do list, i want the user to be able to edit and delete the added tasks, this will be possible by removing `readonly`attribute from HTML. but i am struggling doing the edit function.

Here is my code:

```js
    const formulario=document.getElementById("new-task-form");
    const lista=document.getElementById("list");
    const input=document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
    
    let id=0;
    
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        //console.log("activado");
        e.preventDefault();
        addTask();
    
    });
    
    let addTask=()=>{
        id++;
        let task=input.value;
        lista.innerHTML+=`<div id="tasks">
        <div class="task" id="taskin">
             <div class="content" id="${id}">
                 <input 
                 id="${id}"
                 type="text"
                 class="text"
                 value=${task}
                 readonly
                 />
             </div>
             <div class="actions">
                 <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                 <button class="delete">Delete</button>
             </div>
            </div> 
        </div> `
    
        input.value='';
    }
    
    
    
    lista.addEventListener('click', (evento)=>{
        console.log(evento);
        if(evento.target.className=="edit"){
            console.log("Editar");
        }else if(evento.target.className=="delete"){
            console.log("Borrar");
            
    
        }
    })
```

```html
    <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form action="#" id="new-task-form"> <!--Formulario para poner tareas-->
            <input type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="Que vas a hacer" />
            <input  type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="Add Task" />
        </form>
    </header>
        
    <main>
        <div id="list" class="task-list">
            
            <h2>Tasks</h2>

            <div id="tasks">
               
               <!-- <div class="task">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input type="text" 
                        class="text"
                        value="My Task"
                        readonly
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div> -->

            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>.
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: The `readonly` attribute does not apply to divs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some lines to your JS code. Please check.

```
    lista.addEventListener('click', (evento)=>{
    let parentEl = evento.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    let input = parentEl.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(evento.target.className=="edit"){
        console.log("Editar");
        input[0].removeAttribute('readonly');
    }else if(evento.target.className=="delete"){
        console.log("Borrar");
    }
    })
```

Test it in the Snippet below:

```js
const formulario=document.getElementById("new-task-form");
    const lista=document.getElementById("list");
    const input=document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
    
    let id=0;
    
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        //console.log("activado");
        e.preventDefault();
        addTask();
    
    });
    
    let addTask=()=>{
        id++;
        let task=input.value;
        lista.innerHTML+=`<div id="tasks">
        <div class="task" id="taskin">
             <div class="content" id="${id}">
                 <input 
                 id="${id}"
                 type="text"
                 class="text"
                 value=${task}
                 readonly
                 />
             </div>
             <div class="actions">
                 <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                 <button class="delete">Delete</button>
             </div>
            </div> 
        </div> `
    
        input.value='';
    }
    
    
    
    lista.addEventListener('click', (evento)=>{
        let parentEl = evento.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        let input = parentEl.getElementsByTagName('input');
        console.log(input[0]);
        if(evento.target.className=="edit"){
            input[0].removeAttribute('readonly');
            console.log("Editar");
        }else if(evento.target.className=="delete"){
            console.log("Borrar");
            
    
        }
    })
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form action="#" id="new-task-form"> <!--Formulario para poner tareas-->
            <input type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="Que vas a hacer" />
            <input  type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="Add Task" />
        </form>
    </header>
        
    <main>
        <div id="list" class="task-list">
            
            <h2>Tasks</h2>

            <div id="tasks">
               
               <!-- <div class="task">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input type="text" 
                        class="text"
                        value="My Task"
                        readonly
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div> -->

            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>.
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked! thanks a lot.
One last question, what exactly does the input[0] line?

Comment: Try logging ```input``` variable and you will understand. Input returns an object with multiple values like selected element, length, and so on... I need to select that particular element only and that was indexed by "0". That's why I used ```input[0]``` here.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection, most DOM methods only work on a single element.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, 2 elements have the same `id` 's value :

   `<div class="content" id="${id}">` and `<input id="${id}">`
2. You can change same as :

```js
const formulario=document.getElementById("new-task-form");
    const lista=document.getElementById("list");
    const input=document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
    
    let id=0;
    
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        //console.log("activado");
        e.preventDefault();
        addTask();
    
    });
    
    let addTask=()=>{
        id++;
        let task=input.value;
        lista.innerHTML+=`<div id="tasks">
        <div class="task" id="taskin">
             <div class="content" id="${id}">
                 <input 
                 id="input-${id}"
                 type="text"
                 class="text"
                 value=${task}
                 readonly
                 />
             </div>
             <div class="actions">
                 <button class="edit" data-task_id="input-${id}">Edit</button>
                 <button class="delete" data-task_id="input-${id}">Delete</button>
             </div>
            </div> 
        </div> `
    
        input.value='';
    }
    
    
    
    lista.addEventListener('click', (evento)=>{
        if(evento.target.className=="edit"){
            document.getElementById(evento.target.dataset.task_id).removeAttribute('readonly');
        }else if(evento.target.className=="delete"){
            document.getElementById(evento.target.dataset.task_id).remove();
            
    
        }
    })
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form action="#" id="new-task-form"> <!--Formulario para poner tareas-->
            <input type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="Que vas a hacer" />
            <input  type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="Add Task" />
        </form>
    </header>
        
    <main>
        <div id="list" class="task-list">
            
            <h2>Tasks</h2>

            <div id="tasks">
               
               <!-- <div class="task">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input type="text" 
                        class="text"
                        value="My Task"
                        readonly
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div> -->

            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean remove the `readonly` attribute on textbox inside the three divs?

```js
$('.edit').click(function(){

$('.first_div input, .second_div input, .third_div input').removeAttr('readonly');

});



$('.edit_first').click(function(){

$('#first_textbox').removeAttr('readonly');

});

$('.edit_second').click(function(){

$('#second_textbox').removeAttr('readonly');

});

$('.edit_third').click(function(){

$('#third_textbox').removeAttr('readonly');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_div">
<input readonly id="first_textbox">
</div>
<div class="second_div">
<input readonly id="second_textbox">
</div>
<div class="third_div">
<input readonly id="third_textbox">
</div>
<button class="edit">Edit All</button>
<button class="edit_first">Edit first textbox</button>
<button class="edit_second">Edit second textbox</button>
<button class="edit_third">Edit third textbox</button>
```